# Finding minimum value according to a comparator

Tags: java, apache-commons

I was wondering if there is a way to find the minimum or maximum of a collection using a comparator in the Apache commons-collection library. Something equivalent to this using Guava:

```
return Ordering.from(comparator).max(collection);
```

Comment: Apache commons collections are all based on `java.util.Collection`. Therefore there is nothing specific to Apache that you should be aware of in this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`java.util.Collections` has methods

```
max(Collection) // natural order
max(Collection, Comparator) // according to compare provided

min(Collection)   // natural order
min(Collection, Comparator)  // according to compare provided
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use the [min](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min-java.util.Collection-) and [max](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-java.util.Comparator-) methods of the Collection class?

Example:

```
  LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
  list.add(-15);  
  list.add(33);  
  list.add(-23);  
  list.add(11); 
  System.out.println("Max value: " + Collections.max(list,comparator));
```

Answer (score 0):

like so:

```
Item getMax(Collection<Item> items, Comparator<Item> comparator) {
    Item temp = null;
    for(Item item : items) {
        if(temp == null || comparator.compare(temp, item) < 0)
            temp = item;
    }
    return temp;
}

Item getMin(Collection<Item> items, Comparator<Item> comparator) {
    Item temp = null;
    for(Item item : items) {
        if(temp == null || comparator.compare(temp, item) > 0)
            temp = item;
    }
    return temp;
}
```